# Finding out *what* is synchronizing two Linux servers

Tags: files, synchronization

The last person to maintain these Red Hat servers somehow set it up so they stay in sync -- if I delete files on one it automatically deletes them on the other. I need to set up a new configuration on just one of them, so I need to disable the synchronization, but I don't know what's causing it. Where should I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious way, especially if the synchronization is instant, is that they may be using a network filesystem. Confirm that you're not looking at an NFS, AFS, etc. mount. `/etc/fstab` is a good place to start. An alternative is there may be a cluster filesystem running (once again, `/etc/fstab` is a good place to start).

Now, if its not instant (or even if it is, some of these programs are fairly quick), there are several tools that do this; possibly the most common is `rsync`. Usually that'd be run from a cron job somewhere, so check user and system crontabs. Normally, `rsync` is run in a master-slave setup, though, not multi-master. There are others, such as `unison`. Some run as daemons; check which processes are running (`ps fxa` for example). You can usually figure out what something is either with `man` or Google.

There are a bunch of commercial offerings, too. Looking at /usr/local, /opt, and installed packages may help here.

Comment: There is no fstab on the server, I'm going to look at rsync I keep you informed. 1000 thanks

Comment: @user1040899: There is no `/etc/fstab`‽ That's weird. FYI, that's a plain-text file, not a command to run... I'm guessing you know that, just want to be sure. Anyway, you can also see mounted filesystems by running `mount` or looking at `/proc/mounts`

Comment: Oups I'm really a noob... there is fstab but not a folder... I find  some informations in it I'll dig from here, thank you very much :-)

Comment: @user1040899: I'm not sure what these servers are, but I'd strongly recommend *not* learning Linux on a system where *oops, I broke it* would be a problem. And depending on how complicated this replication setup is, breaking the system might be easy to do by mistake.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but unfortunately I got no choice :-( Ok I commented the lines that I don't want to synchronize in /etc/fstab but seems to continue replicating... do I need to restart something to make it work ? Or do I need to do the modification on the 2 servers ? Cause it replicates on a NAS server both of them, I forgot to mention that, if I stop 1 to replicate on that NAS server it must be good, but the main one I don't want to stop his replication

Comment: If it's an NFS mount of the NAS server, then its not so much *replicating* as that the files are actually located on the NAS server. In the Windows world, it'd be a mapped network drive, if you're more familiar with that. `/etc/fstab` just says what to mount at boot—changing it won't do anything until the next boot. To change on the fly, use the `mount` and `umount` commands. You need to read up on Linux administration, its not going to be possible to cover it all in Unix.SE comments…

Comment: Ok just a reply to tell you that I succeeded, everything is OK I just rebooted the server. A million thanks !!